# AWS bastion host to ec2 instance. SSH forwarding is not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

At AWS cloud platform, I provisioned a bastion host and ec2 instances. I would like to login to ec2 instances from the bastion host using ssh agent forwarding. It is not working. Here is what I've done.

1. At my local ubuntu laptop:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
 ForwardAgent yes
```

2. start the ssh-agent

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

3. login to bastion host

```
ssh -A -i key.pem ubuntu@36.21.16.177
```

4. I successfully logged into bastion host.
5. At the bastion host, login to an ec2 instance. I got permission denied.

```
ssh -A 10.1.11.21
ubuntu@10.1.11.21: Permission denied (publickey).
```

6. I copied key.pem to the bastion host. With the key.pem, I am able to login to ec2 instance from bastion host. At the bastion host,

```
ssh -i key.pem 10.1.11.21
```

I prefer not to copy key.pem to every ec2 instance. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following and then retry to connect using the same key file :
`chmod 400 key.pem`